# How to change an image <img> on mouse rollover (hover)

Tags: html, css, image

How can I change an image (set using `<img>` tag, which is not a `<div>` or `<some_selector>` background, that can be easily solved by changing `background` or `background-image` attribute on `:hover` in CSS) on mouse rollover (hover) like the favorite tag remove button in stackoverflow homepage, in which the **(X)** image becomes red on hover ?

Comment: Removed tag "image-processing".

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**HTML**

```
<div id="css-image-swap-1">
<img id="swap-1" src="default-image-url" alt="CSS image swap" />
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
#css-image-swap-1{
    width:300px; height:150px; background:url(swap-image-url);
}
#css-image-swap-1 img:hover{
    opacity:0;
}
```