# How to Change the hover image in CSS

Tags: html, css

Hello Friends When i **Inspect element** my Code is so far ...

```
<div class="ja-megamenu " id="ja-megamenu">
    <ul class="megamenu level0">
        <li  class="mega first active">
            <a href="http://127.0.0.1/"  class="mega first active" id="menu435" >
                <span class="has-image" >
                    <img src=images/on_home.png>
                </span>
            </a>
        </li>
       <li  class="mega haschild">
            <a href="/index.php?option=com_community&amp;view=frontpage&amp;Itemid=455"  class="mega haschild" id="menu455" title="Grower Community">
                <span class="has-image" >
                    <img src=images/active_11.png>
                </span>
            </a>
            <div class="childcontent cols1 ">
                <div class="childcontent-inner-wrap">
                    <div class="childcontent-inner clearfix" style="width: 200px;">
                        <div class="megacol column1 first" style="width: 200px;">
                            <ul class="megamenu level1">
                                <li  class="mega first">
                                    <div class="group">
                                        <div class="group-title">
                                            <a href="/index.php?option=com_community&amp;view=photos&amp;Itemid=507" class="mega first" id="menu507" title="Photos">
                                                <span class="has-image" >
                                                    <img src=images/wt_under_link_01_01.png>
                                                </span>
                                            </a>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </li>
                                <li class="mega last">
                                    <a href="/index.php?option=com_allvideoshare&amp;view=category&amp;slg=0&amp;orderby=default&amp;Itemid=934"  class="mega last" id="menu934" title="Videos">
                                        <span class="has-image" >
                                            <img src=images/wt_under_link_01_02.png>    
                                        </span>
                                    </a>
                                </li>
                            </ul>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </li>
        <li  class="mega">
            <a href="/index.php?option=com_kunena&amp;view=topics&amp;mode=replies&amp;Itemid=506"  class="mega" id="menu506" title="Forum">
                <span class="has-image" >
                    <img src=images/active_05.png>
                </span>
            </a>
        </li>
        <li  class="mega last">
            <a href="/index.php?option=com_easyblog&amp;view=blogger&amp;limit=-2&amp;Itemid=944" class="mega last" id="menu944" title="Blog">
                <span class="has-image" >
                    <img src=images/active_07.png>
                </span>
            </a>        
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Now here I want to change the image on hover ...

I am using somehing like this

```
.ja-megamenu ul.level0 li.mega a.mega span.has-image:hover{
    background:url(../../images/act_05.png) no-repeat 0 0;
}
```

but the image hover is not occurs ... can any one please help me

I think hover is not happens due to span ...

please suggest me what i can do here ?

Comment: how about using `a.mega:hover span.has-image` instead?

Comment: You should try to simplify your html before posting it on SO. Remove everything that has nothing to do with the problem.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5220014/how-to-change-an-image-on-mouse-rollover-hover

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As it's been said already, the background image will not display as long as you have an image over it, so you could use this to hide the image when hovering the `span`:

```
.ja-megamenu ul.level0 li.mega a.mega span.has-image:hover > img {
    visibility:hidden;
}
```

See this [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/cjtpB/)

Comment: hey after hidden is it possible to over the other image on the same place .. if yes please show my how ?

Comment: I simply want to hover the images.. when user mouse over ..through CSS, I do not want to use javascript ... Something like this http://relaxindore.com/menu/dropdowntabsdemo.htm

Comment: Ok, so I think [this jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/cjtpB/) is what you're looking for

Comment: I guess what you want is the [:active selector](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_active.asp)

Comment: Now I realise that the previous jsfiddle already has that behaviour (Note that `active` means _at the moment it is clicked_)

Comment: :) so what i can do ? suppose I want to place the same image after Click thenafter user is able to know in which page they are

Comment: Oh now I see what you want. The most common way of doing that is adding a class to the element where you currently are and then apply the css to that only element. Actually, you already have that class added in your code! So with this [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/cjtpB/1/) you should be fine. (You need to manually change the `active` class depending in which page you are)

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend applying the `:hover` pseudo-class to the anchor (`a.mega:hover`) then changing the child `<span>` beneath it.

```
.ja-megamenu ul.level0 li.mega a.mega:hover span.has-image {
    /* background change */
}
```

Keep in mind that as long as there is a child `<img>` within the span, that's going to overlap whatever you have set a background on the span. That is to say the span's background will never overcome the `<img src="...">` in terms of visuals.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are trying to change the background image of the span and not the src of the image tag.

In order to do that you would probably have better luck with using jQuery.