# How to change image on mouseover with d3.js

Tags: javascript, svg, d3.js

I have some svg circles and images in them, generated with d3.js. I want to change images on mouseover instead of tooltip.

```
mask.append("image")
    .attr('class', "sth")
    .attr('x',-(entry.childNodes[0].getAttribute("r"))-40)
    .attr('y',-(entry.childNodes[0].getAttribute("r"))-40)
    .attr('width', 80+entry.childNodes[0].getAttribute("r")*2)
    .attr('height', 80+entry.childNodes[0].getAttribute("r")*2)
    .attr("transform", entry.childNodes[0].getAttribute("transform"))
    .attr('clip-path', 'url(#'+('clip'+clipPathId)+')')
    .attr("xlink:href", imageUrl)
    .on("click", function(d) { 
          zoom(d);                           
          d3.event.stopPropagation(); 
    })
    .on("mouseover", function(d){ d.attr("xlink:href", "img/001.jpg"); tooltip.style("visibility", "visible"); tooltip.html("<img src='"+imageUrl+"'/>"); })
    .on("mousemove", function(){ tooltip.style("top", (d3.event.pageY-10)+"px").style("left",(d3.event.pageX+10)+"px"); })
    .on("mouseout", function(){ tooltip.style("visibility", "hidden"); }); 
                    ;
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to change an image <img> on mouse rollover (hover)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5220014/how-to-change-an-image-img-on-mouse-rollover-hover)

Comment: No. I would like to do it with js, because next step is automatically spinning array of images when mouse over.

Comment: I get error: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'attr' of undefined

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`d` is the data element bound to the node.  `this` is the node itself:

Try:

```
.on("mouseover", function(d){ 
    d3.select(this).attr("xlink:href", "img/001.jpg");
})
```